# convert any site into responsive site through bootstrap error

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

hi I am using bootstrap from a month and I know how to change any site into responsive site through bootstrap.

there is a site which i want to change into the responsive site. i specify the bootstrap library and then i run it. but then i see that only few things are responsive like about page text, event and menu but i want all the things into responsive like slider, contact page and gallery page which is not responsive. what should i do ????

Comment: Welcome to SO, you need to ask specific question on specific issues to get an answer, you question is way too broad

Comment: You should note what the exact problem is, why can't you do those things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its is very easy to make your website responsive with bootstrap just include bootstrap library. You can download it from [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) and you can also include on-line library of bootstrap

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and just include class to `<div>` it will make your site responsive. and you can find more help from [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)  and if you can submit some code I will help you more feather.

Comment: But i will tell you should google it first before posting question. you can learn rules from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask cause this is not a proper Question.